# Grouping the elements of an Array with the help of a bin Array

Tags: c#, linq

Assume that we have an array:

```
int[] values = new int[10];
values[0] = 1;
values[1] = 2;
values[2] = 3;
values[3] = 4;
values[4] = 6;
values[5] = 8;
values[6] = 2;
values[7] = 1;
values[8] = 3;
values[9] = 9;
```

And I have another array, say, the def array that defines the buckets:

```
int[] def= new int[3]; // defs holds the definition of the buckets
def[0] = 0;
def[1] = 5;
def2] = 10;
```

I want to use this def array to group the values array, in order to get the frequency distribution, using c#:

i.e.

```
bin[0] = 7; // the number of array values that lies between 0 and 5
bin[1] = 3; // the number of array values that lies between 5 and 10
```

I already found a solution with loops, but I am sure there is more elegant and neater way to do this operation; the linq / group by method.

How can I code this procedure using LINQ Group By?

Thanks in advance for anyone contributing to the answer,

Aykut

Comment: What is `def` in the sample?

Comment: Can you properly explain the logic of bin[0] = 7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bin =
    array
        .GroupBy(x => x / 5)
        .Select(x => x.Count())
        .ToArray();
```

Or better yet this:

```
var lookup = array.ToLookup(x => x / 5);
var bin =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, lookup.Max(x => x.Key) + 1)
        .Select(x => lookup[x].Count())
        .ToArray();
```

This second example works if there are some outlying numbers in the original array.

Or even better, using `buckets`:

```
var buckets = new [] { 0, 5, 10, };
var lookup = array.ToLookup(x => buckets.Where(b => x >= b).Count() - 1);
var bin =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, lookup.Max(x => x.Key) + 1)
        .Select(x => lookup[x].Count())
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Enigmativity, your first suggestion would be of great use when the buckets are indeterminate. Thanks four this extensive work. Well done. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If I've understood you correctly, then you're looking something like this:

```
var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 2, 1, 3, 9 };
var buckets = new[] { 0, 5, 10 };
var distributionFreq = buckets
    .Skip(1) // we don't need the first bucket
    .OrderBy(bucket => bucket) // just ensure, that buckets are ordered properly
    .Select((bucket, i) => new
    {
        Min = buckets[i], // minimal value of range
        Max = bucket // maximal value of range
    })
    .Select(range => new
    {
        Range = range,
        NumberOfValuesAtRange = array.Count(item => item > range.Min && item < range.Max)
    })
    .ToArray();
```

First, you have to define the range of values (0..5, 5..10, and so on).
Second, count the number of values in source array, which fits the range.

Note, that you should define more precisely the criteria for the outermost values, e.g. does the value of 5 fits the first range, or the second one?

Comment: Splendid. Thanks a lot Dennis.